# How to join a range into a formatted string using Arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have the following data in Range("A1:B2")

```
A1: 190-00-001-00
A2: 190-00-002-00
B1: 00
B2: 00
```

My goal is to get it in a string that ultimately looks like this: (('190-00-001-00','00'),('190-00-002-00','00'))
How can I code this in VBA with Arrays?

Comment: How do I make it dynamic, so that I could have 100 rows and it would still working?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Sub makestring()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range, sq As String
    Dim arr(1 To 4) As String, i As Long
    Set rng = Range("A1:B2")

    sq = "'"
    i = 1

    For Each r In rng
        arr(i) = sq & r.Text & sq
        i = i + 1
    Next r

    output = "((" & arr(1) & "," & arr(2) & "),(" & arr(3) & "," & arr(4) & "))"
    MsgBox output
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How do I make it dynamic now? Meaning, instead of 2 rows, there could be 100 rows.